# Apache Spark Auto Scaling properties - Add Worker on the Fly

Tags: scala, apache-spark, mapreduce, bigdata

During the execution of a Spark Program, let's say,

reading 10GB of data into memory, and just doing a filtering, a map, and then saving in another storage.

Can I auto-scale the cluster based on the load, and for instance add more Worker Nodes to the Program, if this program eventually needs to hangle 1TB instead of 10GB ?

If this is possible, how can it be done?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to some extent, using [dynamic allocation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/job-scheduling.html#dynamic-resource-allocation), but behavior is dependent on the job latency, not direct usage of particular resource.

You have to remember that in general, Spark can handle data larger than memory just fine, and memory problems are usually caused by user mistakes, or vicious garbage collecting cycles. None of these could be easily solved, by "adding more resources".

Comment: What do you mean by “viscous garbage collecting cycles”?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using any of the cloud platforms for creating the cluster you can use auto-scaling functionality. that will scale cluster horizontally(number of nodes with change)

Answer (score 0):

Agree with @user8889543 - You can read much more data then your memory.

And as for adding more resources on the fly. It is depended on your cluster type.
I use standalone mode, and I have a code that add on the fly machines that attached to the master automatically, then my cluster has more cores and memory.

If you only have on job/program in the cluster then it is pretty simple. Just set

> spark.cores.max

to a very high number and the job will take all the cores of the cluster always. [see](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#scheduling)

If you have several jobs in the cluster it becomes complicate. as mentioned in  @user8889543 answer.